# Strange error not found in a monte carlo code, Infinite expression 1/0 encountered

Tags: plotting, chemistry, modeling, broken-code, error-tracking

I've been trying to code a kinetic monte carlo simulation for a dimerization reaction, 2M ---> D. However I have a kinetic Monte Carlo code for a first order decomposition reaction of AIBN (that's the name of the chemical compound)

The code for AIBN decomposition works perfectly, but when I try to copy it to use it for the M compound, the code fails and Mathematica goes in a infinite loop saying: "Power: Infinte expression 1/0 encountered " and then it says "Infinity:Indeterminite expression o Complexinfinity encountered".

I don't know why the AIBN code works and the dimerization code for M doesn't if is exactly the same structure. Mathematica only graphs the analytical solution for M but doesn't graph the outputstream resulting from the while Loop for kinetic Monte Carlo.

**Here is the code that works, for the AIBN decomposition**

```
AIBN0 = 0.01;(*mol/L*)
R = 1.98;TK = 60 + 273.15;
kdi = 2.89*10^(15)*Exp[-31130/(R*TK)];(* s^-1*)
tf = 3600;(*%s*)
ta = {t, 0, tf};
AIBN = (AIBN0)*Exp[-kdi*t];
p1 = Plot[AIBN, ta , PlotStyle -> Red];
NAV = 2*10^6;
XAIBN = AIBN0*NAV;
kdiMC = kdi;
tb = 0.0;
AIBN = AIBN0;
Niter = 0;
file = OpenWrite["Result1.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm]
toc = Timing[
   While[tb < tf,
    Write[file, tb, " ", AIBN];
    Niter = Niter + 1;
    a0 = kdiMC*XAIBN;
    XAIBN = XAIBN - 1;
    AIBN = XAIBN/NAV;
    tb = tb - Log[RandomReal[]]/a0]];
Print[Niter, toc]
Close[file];
Result = Import["Result1.dat"];
p2 = ListPlot[Result, DataRange -> {0, 600}];
Show[p1, p2]
```

**Here the code that doesn't work, for the M compound dimerization**

```
Mo = 5; (*mol/L*) (*Initial concentration of M*)
R = 1.98 (*J/(mol K)*); (*Ideal Gas constant*)
Tk = 383; (*K, Temperature*)
kdim = 2.52(10^4)Exp[(-22347/(R*Tk))] (*L/(mol s)*) (*Kinetic constant*)
tf = 30000(60)(60); (*s, final reaction time, 30'000 hours*)
M = Mo/(1 + 2 kdim *t *Mo); (*Analytical solution*)
p6 = Plot[
       M, {t, 0, tf}, 
       PlotLabel -> "Concentration vs Time", 
       AxesLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Concentration (mol/L)"}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotLegends -> {"[M]"}]
NAV = 2*10^3; (*Avogadro number times Volume, (molecules L)/mol*)
XM = Mo*NAV; (* number of M molecules*)
kdimMC = 2*kdim/NAV; (*Monte Carlo kinetic constant*)
tb = 0.0; (*FIrst Iteration time*)
M = Mo; (*First Concentration Value of M*)
Niter = 0; (*First Iteration*)
file = OpenWrite["Result3.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm]
toc = Timing[
        While[
         tb <= tf, 
         Write[file, tb, " ", M]; 
         Niter = Niter + 1; 
         a0 = kdimMC*XM*(XM - 1)/2; 
         XM = XM - 2; 
         M = XM/NAV; 
         tb = tb - Log[RandomReal[]]/a0
        ]
      ];
Print[Niter, toc]
Close[file];
Result = Import["Result3.dat"];
p9 = ListPlot[Result, DataRange -> {0, 108000000}];
Show[p6, p9]
```

Comment: Don't do this: `Write[file, tb, " ", M];` , do this instead `Write[file, {tb, M}];` and remove `, FormatType -> OutputForm` when you open the file.

Comment: It's a bit strange writing the results to the file during the loop, and this incurs some overhead. You would be better off `Sow`-ing them, and then `Reap`-ing them to a list, then write that list out to a file afterwards.

Comment: I have already implemented the suggestions in the broken code, doing ````Write[file,{tb,M}];``` and removing  ```,FormatType->OutputForm``` when I open the file. However, now what happen is that Mathematica only shows p6 when ```Show[p6,p9]``` command is executed. If I only put ```Show[p9]``` (in order to graph only the numerical solution of resulting from the Kinetic Monte Carlo algorithm), Mathematica returns only the axes.

Comment: I don't know how to implement Sow and Reap in my code, I'm sorry, could you explain me? Thank you

Comment: @flinty mathematica should show a dotted graph for M, like the first code, for the AIBN, which represent a random walk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Reap` and `Sow` to build up a list of data, `Export` it all in one go, and there's no need to re-import it just to plot the results:

```
Mo = 5;
(*mol/L*)
(*Initial concentration of M*)

R = 1.98
(*J/(mol \K)*);
(*Ideal Gas constant*)

Tk = 383;
(*K,Temperature*)

kdim = 2.52 (10^4) Exp[(-22347/(R*Tk))]
(*L/(mol s)*)
(*Kinetic constant*)

tf = 30000 (60) (60);
(*s,final reaction time,30'000 hours*)

M = Mo/(1 + 2 kdim*t*Mo);
(*Analytical solution*)

p6 = Plot[M, {t, 0, tf}, PlotLabel -> "Concentration vs Time", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Concentration (mol/L)"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotLegends -> {"[M]"}]

NAV = 2*10^3;
(*Avogadro number times Volume,(molecules L)/mol*)

XM = Mo*NAV;
(*number of M molecules*)

kdimMC = 2*kdim/NAV;
(*Monte Carlo kinetic constant*)

tb = 0.0;
(*FIrst Iteration time*)

M = Mo;
(*First Concentration Value of M*)

Niter = 0;
(*First Iteration*)

toc = Timing[
   result = Reap[While[tb <= tf, Sow[{tb, M}];
        Niter = Niter + 1;
        a0 = kdimMC*XM*(XM - 1)/2;
        XM = XM - 2;
        M = XM/NAV;
        tb = tb - Log[RandomReal[]]/a0]][[2, 1]];
   ];

Export["Result3.dat", result];

Print["iterations:" , Niter, "\ntiming:", First[toc]]

p9 = ListPlot[result, DataRange -> {0, 108000000}];
Show[p6, p9]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you so much!!