# Error in Monte Carlo simulation. Now Random walk (dotted curve) doesn't fit to the analytical curve (dashed curve)

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, chemistry, modeling, broken-code

I've been trying to code a kinetic monte carlo simulation for a system of consecutive chemical reactions using a fixed (repaired) code that the user flinty gives me in the last questions I post:
[Strange error not found in a monte carlo code, Infinite expression 1/0 encountered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227917/strange-error-not-found-in-a-monte-carlo-code-infinite-expression-1-0-encounter/227969#227969).
In that post, the original code for one chemical reaction fail  because of the use of Import and FormatType function, and it was fixed using Reap and Sow.
Now I have a code that works perfectly using again Import and FormatType but it fails when I try to implement Reap and Sow on it.

The aim is to obtain the concentration of every chemical compound involved in a system of 2 chemical reactions.

The Reason why I don't want to use Import and FormatType is because when I try to add mor chemical reactions it fails, I mean, If you change something of that code, it gets broken also.

I don't undesrtand whats wrong if the Reap and Sow structure is similar to the code for one chemical reaction

**Here the Code that works using Reap and Sow for One chemical Reaction, Dimerization, 2M-->D**

```
Mo = 5; (*mol/L*) (*Initial concentration of M, Monomer*)
DDo = 0; (*mol/L*) (*Initial concentration of D, Dimer*)
R = 1.98 ;(*J/(mol K), Ideal Gas constant*)
Tk = 383; (*K, Tmperature of the reaction in kelvin*)
kdim = 2.52*10^4*E^(-22347/(R*Tk)); (*L/(mol s), kinetic constant*)
tf = 30000*60*60; (*s, final time in seconds, 30'000 hours of reaction*)

M = Mo/(1 + 2*kdim*t*Mo); (*Analytical solution for the ODE system, for M*)

DD = (2*kdim*t* Mo^2 + DDo + 2*kdim*t* Mo*DDo)/(1 + 2*kdim*t*Mo); (*Analytical solution for the ODE system, for D*)

p8 = Plot[{M, DD}, {t, 0, tf}, PlotLabel -> "Concentration vs Time", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Concentration mol/L"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotLegends -> {"[M]", "[D]"}];

(*Kinetic Monte Carlo loop starts here*)

Mo = 5;
R = 1.98;
Tk = 383;
kdim = 2.52*10^4*Exp[-22347/(R*Tk)];

tf = 30000*60*60

M = Mo/(1 + 2*kdim*t*Mo);

p6 = Plot[M, {t, 0, tf}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AxesLabel -> {"time (s)", "Concentration (mol/L)"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"[M]"}, PlotLabel -> "Concentration of M"];

NAV = 2*10^3; (*Avogadro number times system volume*)

XM = Mo*NAV; (*Number of M molecules*)

kdimMC = 2*(kdim/NAV); (*Kinetic Monte carlo constant*)

tb = 0.0;

M = Mo;

Niter = 0;

toc = Timing[
   result = 
    Reap[While[tb <= tf, Sow[{tb, M}]; Niter = Niter + 1; 
       a0 = kdimMC*XM*(XM - 1)/2; XM = XM - 2; M = XM/NAV; 
       tb = tb - Log[RandomReal[]]/a0]][[2, 1]]];

Export["Result3.dat", result];

Print["iterations for M:", Niter, "\ntiming for M", First[toc]]

p9 = ListPlot[result, DataRange -> {0, tf}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotLegends -> {"kMC [M]"}];

Mo = 5;
DDo = 0;
R = 1.98;
Tk = 383;

kdim = 2.52*10^4*Exp[-22347/(R*Tk)];

tf = 30000*60*60

M = Mo/(1 + 2*kdim*t*Mo);

DD = (2*kdim*t*Mo^2 + DDo + 2*kdim*t*Mo*DDo)/(1 + 2*kdim*t*Mo);

p7 = Plot[DD, {t, 0, tf}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   AxesLabel -> {"time (s)", "Concentration (mol/L)"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"[D]"}, PlotLabel -> "Concentration of D"];

NAV = 2*10^3; (*Avogadro number times system volume*)

XM = Mo*NAV; (*Initial number of molecules of M*)

XDD = DDo*NAV/2; (*It's divide by 2 because there must be half of the number of molecules of D regarding the number of M molecules, due to D is a Dimer of M*)

kdimMC = 2*(kdim/NAV); (*kinetic monte carlo constant*)

tb = 0.0;

M = Mo;

DD = DDo;

Niter = 0;

toc = Timing[result = Reap[While[tb <= tf, Sow[{tb, DD}];
       Niter = Niter + 1;
       a0 = kdimMC*XM*(XM - 1)/2;
       XM = XM - 2;
       XDD = XDD + 1;
       M = XM/NAV;
       DD = Mo - M;(*by stoichiometry, we can rewrite D concentration like this, just a mass balance*)
       tb = tb - Log[RandomReal[]]/a0]][[2, 1]]];

Export["Result3.dat", result];

Print["iterations for D:", Niter, "\ntiming for D", First[toc]]

p10 = ListPlot[result, DataRange -> {0, tf}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   PlotLegends -> {"kMC [D]"}];

Show[p8, p9, p10, PlotRange -> {{0, tf}, {0, 5}}]
```

**Here the code that works using Import and FormatType for the consecutive reactions A-->B; B-->C**

```
A0 = 1.00;(*mol/L, initial concentration of A*)
B0 = 0.00;(*mol/L, initial concentration of B*)
C0 = 0.00;(*mol/L, Initial concentration of C*)

k1 = 2*10^(-4);(* s^-1, kinetic constant for the reaction A-->B*)
k2 = 1*10^(-4);(* s^-1, kinetic constant for the reaction B-->C*)

tf = 3600*5;(*s, final time*)

ta = {t, 0, tf}; (*Interval of time*)

A = A0*Exp[-k1*t]; (*Analytical solution for A*)

B = B0*Exp[-k2*t] + (A0*k1/(k2 - k1))*(Exp[-k1*t] - Exp[-k2*t]); (*Analytical solution for B*)

Cs = A0 + B0 + C0 - A - B; (*Analytical solution for C*)

p1 = Plot[A, ta ,  PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
p2 = Plot[B, ta , PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}];
p3 = Plot[Cs, ta , PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Gray}];

NAV = 2*10^3; (*Avogadro number times volume system*)

XA = A0*NAV; (*Number of molecules of A*)
XB = B0*NAV; (*Number of molecules of B*)
XC = C0*NAV; (*Number of molecules of C*)

k1MC = k1; (*Kinetic monte carlo constant*)
k2MC = k2; (*Kinetic Monte Carlo constant*)

Maxr = 2;  (*Maximum number of reactions*)

kmax = Ceiling[Log2[Maxr]]; (*Number of Steps, or movements, needed to occur one of the two possible reactions*)

VR = Table[0.0, {i, 1, 1 kmax + 1}, {j, 1, 2^kmax}]; (*Vector of Reactions*)

tb = 0.0;
Niter = 0;

file = OpenWrite["Result.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm]
toc = Timing[
   While[tb < tf,
    Niter = Niter + 1;
    
    
    VR[[kmax + 1, 1]] = k1MC*XA; (*Reaction 1*)
    
    VR[[kmax + 1, 2]] = k2MC*XB; (*Reaction 2*)

    For[i = 1, i <= kmax + 1, i++,
     For[j = 1, j <= 2^(kmax - i), j++,
       VR[[kmax + 1 - i, j]] = 
         VR[[kmax + 2 - i, 2*j]] + VR[[kmax + 2 - i, 2*j - 1]];
       ];];
    
    a0 = VR[[1, 1]]; (*Total reaction rate*)
    ra0 = RandomReal[]*a0;
    mv = 1;
    
    For[i = 1, i <= kmax, i++,
     If[ra0 <= VR[[i + 1, 2*mv - 1]], mv = 2*mv - 1, 
      ra0 = ra0 - VR[[i + 1, 2*mv - 1]]; mv = 2*mv]];
    
    If [mv == 1, XA = XA - 1; XB = XB + 1;];
    If [mv == 2, XC = XC + 1; XB = XB - 1;];

    A = XA/NAV;
    B = XB/NAV;
    Cs = XC/NAV;

    Write[file, tb, " ", A, " ", B, " ", Cs];
    tb = tb - Log[RandomReal[]]/a0]];

Close[file];
Print[Niter];
Result = Import["Result.dat"];

tb = Result[[All, 1]];
A = Result[[All, 2]];
B = Result[[All, 3]];
Cs = Result[[All, 4]];

p4 = ListPlot[Transpose@{tb, A}, PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Red}];
p5 = ListPlot[Transpose@{tb, B}, PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Blue}];
p6 = ListPlot[Transpose@{tb, Cs}, PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Gray}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

**Here the Broken Code for the system A-->B; B-->C using Reap and Sow;
Updated version: I removed Write [tb," ", A, " ", B, " ", Cs]; and Close[file];
Now doesn't graph the random walk
Updated Version 2: I have implemented the suggestions of flenty, Now the random walk doesn't fit to the analytical curve
Updated 3: Sorry I put B=A-Ao-CS at the line before tb=tb-Log, and the correct line should be B=XB/NAV, that gives the graph at the end **

```
A0 = 1.00; (*mol/L*)
B0 = 0.00;(*mol/L*)
C0 = 0.00;(*mol/L*)

k1 = 2*10^-4; (*s^-1*)
k2 = 1*10^-4; (*s^-1*)

tf = 3600*5; (*s*)
ta = {t, 0, tf};
A = A0*Exp[-k1*t];
B = B0*E^(-k2*t) + (A0*k1)/(k2 - k1)*(E^(-k1*t) - E^(-k2*t));
Cs = A0 + B0 + C0 - A - B;

p1 = Plot[A, ta, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
p2 = Plot[B, ta, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}];
p3 = Plot[Cs, ta, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Gray}];

NAV = 2*10^3; (* (molecules L / mol) Avogadro number times Volume*)

XA = A0*NAV;  (* Number of A molecules *)
XB = B0*NAV;   (* Number of B molecules *)
XC = C0*NAV;   (* Number of C momlecules *)

k1MC = k1; (*Kinetic monte carlo reaction constants*)
k2MC = k2;

Maxr = 2;  (* Number of reactions *)

kmax = Ceiling[
   Log2[Maxr]];   (*Number of steps (or movements) to determine which \
chemical reactions proceeds, according to the binary tree*)

VR = Table[0.0, {i, 1, kmax + 1}, {j, 1, 2^kmax}];

tb = 0.0;

Niter = 0;

ClearAll[A, B, Cs]; A = A0; B = B0; Cs = A0 + B0 + C0 - A - B;

toc = Timing[result = Reap[
      While[tb < tf, Sow[{tb, A, B, Cs}];
       Niter = Niter + 1;
       
       VR[[kmax + 1, 1]] = k1MC*XA; (*R1, reaction 1, 
       VR is Vector of reactions*)
       
       VR[[kmax + 1, 2]] = k2MC*XB; (*R2, reaction 2*)
       
       For[i = 1, i <= kmax + 1, i++,
        For[j = 1, j <= 2^(kmax - i), j++,
          
          VR[[kmax + 1 - i, j]] = 
            VR[[kmax + 2 - i, 2*j]] + VR[[kmax + 2 - i, 2*j - 1]];
          ];];
       a0 = VR[[1, 1]]; (*Total vector of reactionr, VR*)
       ra0 = RandomReal[]*a0;
       mv = 1;
       
       For[i = 1, i <= kmax, i++,
        If[ra0 <= VR[[i + 1, 2*mv - 1]], mv = 2*mv - 1,
         ra0 = ra0 - VR[[i + 1, 2*mv - 1]]; mv = 2*mv]];
       
       If[mv == 1, XA = XA - 1; XB = XB + 1;];
       If[mv == 2, XC = XC + 1; XB = XB - 1;];
       
       A = XA/NAV; (*Concentration of A*)
       B = XB/NAV;
       Cs = XC/NAV;
       
       tb = tb - Log[RandomReal[]]/a0]][[2, 1]]];

Export["Result3.dat", result];
Print["iterations: ", Niter, "\ntiming ", First[toc]]

p4 = ListPlot[Transpose[result], DataRange -> {0, tf}];

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Sow[{tb, , A, B, Cs}]` you have a Null in your list i.e two commas `{... , , ...}` Also if you take a look at `result` you have unevaluated `t`.

Comment: Quick fix: add this `ClearAll[A, B, Cs]; A = A0; B = B0; Cs = A0 + B0 + C0 - A - B;` on the line just before `toc =` and when you do the list plot, instead do `ListPlot[Transpose[result], DataRange -> {0, tf}];`

Comment: I have already removed the Null in ```Sow```, and added the Quick fix on the line just before ```toc =``` and the```ListPlot[Transpose[result],DataRange -> {0,tf}];```
However, now mathematica shows the random walk, but this random walk doesn't fit to the analytical solution curve just like the first two codes does, @flinty, I don't understand what are you saying about ```t``` because the variable of time is ```tb``` and the final time is ```tf```

Comment: The reason you had to Clear A,B,Cs is because your old definitions of A,B,Cs had a t symbol in them. This propagated through the code and you were trying to `ListPlot` them with unevaluated t. `ListPlot` can only take numerical values - that's why I recommended clearing the old definitions before the loop body. I'm afraid I don't know enough chemistry / physics so I can't help with the other problems.